# How can I rephrase this UPDATE INNER JOIN query such that the columns of t1 are accessible in the subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

On running the following MySQL (5.7.12) UPDATE statement, I get the error *"Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't1.col2' in 'where clause'"*.

How can I rephrase this query such that the columns of t1 are accessible in the subquery?

```
UPDATE MyFirstTable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM MySecondTable
    WHERE col2 > t1.col2
) AS t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM MySecondTable
    WHERE col2 < t1.col2
) AS t3
ON t1.col1 = t3.col1 AND t3.col2 = t2.col2
SET t2.col3 = t1.col3;
```

The objective here is to update MyFirstTable with rows from MySecondTable where, for a given col1 value, col2 was both less than and more than t1.col2 (on different rows, of course).

Comment: Do not use subquery - it is excess. Add table aliases to all objects names.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery here, simply make use of a [multi-table update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE  MyFirstTable AS t1
JOIN    MySecondTable AS t2
ON      t1.col1 = t2.col1
SET     t2.col3 = t1.col3
WHERE   t2.col2 > t1.col2;
```

Comment: Current WHERE expression includes the columns from both tables - so logically this condition is a part of joining condition and must be placed into ON clause.

Comment: @Akina - it isn't required that you do that, though you could certainly do so. Personally I prefer to leave the join condition to reference only things that actually logically define the relationship between 2 sets and filters for others (I think it makes more logical sense that way personally). From an optimizer persepctive, it'll be a wash (for inner joins that is).

Comment: *I prefer to leave the join condition to reference only things that actually logically define the relationship between 2 sets and filters for others* Relational condition sets the relation between (at least) two tables. Filter condition filters by one table. If you agree with this then you'd agree that `WHERE t2.col2 > t1.col2` is (a part of) the relation because it uses two tables in the condition expression. If not.. then tell what is relational condition and what is filtering condition from your looking point.

Comment: The only thing in this case that logically defines the relationship between the 2 tables are the keys, anything else is a filter on a set logically. So while again, you could do it either way, neither way is required and neither way is a must - both work, both can be argued to be better/etc., and it's the choice of the author to determine what the 'best' approach is.

Comment: ?? Do you mean that if `col1` is not a key in both tables then you'd treate `t1.col1 = t2.col1` as a filter and 'd use CROSS JOIN with all conditions placed to WHERE? And what you'll do if a column used in the joining condition is not PK but is a part of composite PK? will you treate this condition as joining condition or as a filter?

Comment: Please don't take my questions as an attempt to point out a flaw. I'm just curious to know the rationale for another person's opinion if it doesn't match mine. Perhaps it, or some part of it, will be useful to me.

Comment: @Akina no, that's not what I mean - again, there's no right or wrong here. My original reply was simply to point out that when you said "...MUST be placed into..." that it in fact is not a must, and in any inner-join case, there's little difference to the optimizers how you structure it (if you've been around long enough, you may recall that join conditions alwyas used to be specified in filter clauses and not join conditions).  My preference again is to use the conditions that actually logically define a connection between 2 sets in join conditions, and anything else in filters, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LATERAL`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html

Demo:

```
mysql> select * from myfirsttable;
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    0 |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mysecondtable;
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |   42 |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you discovered, a derived table cannot reference columns of other tables defined in the same FROM clause, which is standard SQL-92 behavior.

I made a couple of small changes to your query because it doesn't make sense the way you wrote it. Your query sets t1.col3 to itself, which doesn't accomplish anything. Also I added col3 to the derived table select-list, so it is available to the outer query.

```
mysql> UPDATE MyFirstTable AS t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM MySecondTable 
  WHERE col2 > t1.col2 
) AS t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 
SET t1.col3 = t2.col3;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't1.col2' in 'where clause'
```

The new feature in SQL:1999 was to make this legal if the derived table is preceded by the `LATERAL` keyword:

```
mysql> UPDATE MyFirstTable AS t1 INNER JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM MySecondTable
  WHERE col2 > t1.col2
) AS t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 
SET t1.col3 = t2.col3;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

With this change, the value of `col3` is copied from t2 to t1:

```
mysql> select * from myfirsttable;                                                                                     
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |   42 |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that support in MySQL for the `LATERAL` feature was implemented in MySQL 8.0.14. If you use an older version of MySQL, you must upgrade to get this feature.